# WCF service host in web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, web-services

I've been tasked with a school project to create a distributed system for a cinema. Requirements are quite simple: have a working model of a cinema booking system (thus I need movies, rooms, shows, bookings and a class for storing personal information), a web service running it, a web interface, and a desktop client for management.

I've taken a flexible solution by creating a shared library that contains definitions for the shared objects, and a separate server and client implementation (ServerReference and ClientReference). It was written to be usable simply by referencing the library, and creating an instance of the specific Reference (then using its Start() and Stop() methods).

I'm using WCF for communication built into the controller layer, and Entity Framework for data storage. As I wanted a dynamic service, I had to ditch the standard WCF configuration for clients and servers, instead creating the endpoints and bindings programmatically.

The problem arose when I tried to create a simple Web Service that can run the ServerReference. As I had a desktop-like environment in my mind during development, I created it like that, only realizing that the solution won't simply work with a web service.

---

Now my problem is the following: the shared library is built on 4.5, but this version ditched the Web Service option. I don't want to write another WCF service to host the services I created, it has to be strictly local (basically, I want a control website, and a web service that can create an instance of ServerReference, and on request, fire the Start() or Stop() events). As Web Service is 3.5 only, I cannot use the shared library (and as the shared library depends greatly on the 4.5 Entity Framework release 6.0.1, I cannot change that either).

My question is: what would be the preferred way of creating such a service? Should I really just create a WCF service runs the ServerReference, or is there a better method?

(Just to note: the goal of this project is to show what we've studied during this semester regarding to web services, web design, parallel programming, regexps, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a fundamental misunderstanding as to which technology to use when.

1. An ASP.NET project is something that does not *run* in the true sense of the word. IIS invokes certain code/delivers the results, but there's nothing *running* like in a desktop application => You can not *host* a WCF service within an ASP.NET page.
2. WCF can be used to create a web service as well, but that does not matter, as the ASP.NET page will be able to communicate with your WCF service through whatever channel.
3. You can host a WCF service either standalone (Windows service for example) or within IIS. It doesn't matter to the client which way you do it, really.
4. An ASP.NET project *is not* a web service!

So what you'd do is:

1. Create the WCF service that does all the operations you need, including reading and writing stuff from/to the database
2. Host this WCF service either standalone or within IIS
3. Create your ASP.NET project with pages to manage movies, rooms, etc. To change or retrieve data, communicate with the WCF service.

Comment: There was no misunderstanding, I'm perfectly clear with the doings of WCF and ASP.NET. Latter was added to the tags as I am creating a web interface for controlling said service. But let me go into details then: I've already created five WCF services to be ran, and a ServerReference that starts this on request (so there's no need for an actual service, it can be ran manually too). I wanted to create a Web Service to initialize and use this ServerReference, but apparently I will have to use WCF

Comment: A `ServerReference` does not "start" a WCF service. The service is hosted by a `ServiceHost` in an application/Windows service or within IIS.

Comment: You clearly have no idea what I'm talking about, so I will try to explain in this short 600 character: I've created a controller for a set of ServiceHosts, called "ServerReference". Now, when I call this ServerReference's "Start" method, it initializes and opens the ServiceHosts. Hence my term "ServerReference that starts this on request". But never mind, I've solved my problem, even after your not-so-helpful attempts at correcting me.

Comment: Please remember - you're the one asking for help, not I. I've been able to get my WCF services running so far. It's clearly not my problem if you're unable to phrase your question so that other people are able to understand you, which is obviously the case as my answer - be it valid or not - is the *only* answer you got.